# Android view binding root property ignored

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use View Binding in android, but the root's property (`layout_gravity, layout_width`) got ignored after build and installed,

it looks fine on design view (`wrap_content` and `center_vertical`).

i've enabled viewBinding in app gradle (android studio 3.6.1), and my root view group is a `LinearLayout` with some property

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
...
```

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

and if i change `layout_gravity` to `center` or other value, it'll get `unresolved reference: ActivityMainBinding` in `MainActivity`

am i not supposed to use property on root layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i switched to dataBinding instead of viewBinding

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
    ...
```